# ggplot2: Y-axis has e values in bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have a dataset with more than 5 million rows, when I write ggplot function the count value which is represented in the y-axis is shown with 'e' values, for example: `3e+06`.
This is not what I want, I want it to just show regular numbers.

This is the code I've written so far:

```
ggplot(data = all_in_one) + geom_bar(mapping = aes(x=member_casual))
```

And this is the plot :
[The bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tR1c.png)

I've tried to add a count function to the y-axis in the aes function, but I didn't know how, plus I don't think that is the problem.

Comment: Try adding `+ scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::label_comma())` to your plot.